# WURFL without a servlet

Tags: java, wurfl

In my database I have a long list of user agents that I require a translation of them, a very promising tool is WURFL, but it has no gradle support and is not very well documented. 
All of the examples I could recover explained how to implement it using a java servlet, but in my case I don't have a servlet or an http request\response just a long list of user agents that need translation, is there a simple way to query WURFL database using a simple java program?

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is to compile the wurfl-cloud-client-java jar yourself (Maven), it can be found in: https://github.com/WURFL/wurfl-cloud-client-java 
there is no jar\maven\gradle available elsewhere.

Then import it to your project and run the following:

```
@Test(groups = "unit")
public class CloudClientUserAgentQueryTest extends Loggable{

private static final String ua = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 7_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/30.0.1599.12 Mobile/11A465 Safari/8536.25 (3B92C18B-D9DE-4CB7-A02A-22FD2AF17C8F)";

private ICloudClientManager ICloudClient;
private AbstractDevice device;
private String[] capabilities;
private String mobile;


@BeforeClass
public void setup() throws Exception {
    CloudClientLoader loader = new CloudClientLoader(null, "/DefaultTest.properties");
    ICloudClient = loader.getClientManager();
}

@BeforeMethod
public void setupDevice() {
    device = ICloudClient.getDeviceFromUserAgent(ua, capabilities);

    Object mobile = device.get("is_wireless_device");
    this.mobile = mobile != null ? mobile.toString() : "unknown";
}

@Test
public void testClient() {
    assertTrue(mobile.equals("true"));
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do it is just using plain old WURFL Java API, which can work with a simple executable Java class. You just have to put it in your classpath (or import it with maven, in case you use it) and do something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String ua = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 7_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/30.0.1599.12 Mobile/11A465 Safari/8536.25 (3B92C18B-D9DE-4CB7-A02A-22FD2AF17C8F)";

  WURFLEngine engine = new GeneralWURFLEngine("path/to/wurfl.zip");

  Device device = engine.getDeviceForRequest(ua);
  System.out.println("Device id: " + device.getId());
  System.out.println("Capability preferred_markup: " + device.getCapability("preferred_markup"));
  System.out.println("Device name: " + device.getCapability("device_name"));
  System.out.println("Brand: " + device.getCapability("brand_name"));
}
```

Please notice that you will need a wurfl file. If you don't have it (current file versions are distributed by Scientiamobile under a commercial license), the previously mentioned cloud client Java can also work.

Answer (score -2):

51Degrees Java API supports offline processing of lists of User-Agents. I have seen an explanation of [how to use this feature on their website](https://51degrees.com/Support/Documentation/Java/offline-application).

However, as a large number of User-Agents contain commas, I would suggest changing the output CSV separator in the code from the above link to something else to avoid confusion.

This method uses a list of User-Agents as an input with one User-Agent per line.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you but I need to use the WURFL one.